# Splitting a dataframe column from scraped webpage based on a delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on getting data from a public API and converting it into a Pandas dataframe basically from US earthquake website. I got JSON form data which is actually list of nested dictionaries. I have Used an approach and converted it into dataframe which is of the form class **'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'**. Now when I am trying to split the coordinates column I am getting NaN or other issues. The series is of the form **class 'pandas.core.series.Series'**.

Here is my code-

```
import urllib.request, json
import pandas as pd
url = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-10-01&endtime=2016-10-02"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
y=data['features']
o=[]
for d in y:
    d.update(d.pop('geometry', {}))
for i in y:
    i.update(i.pop('properties', {}))
#print(y)
df1=pd.DataFrame(y)
print(type(df1))
df1=df1.drop(['alert','cdi','detail','felt','id','ids','mmi','net','sources','updated','url'],axis=1)
print(type(df1['coordinates']))
display(df1)
```

I tried using str.split, Pandas.Series.str.split, slitt

Comment: you should put in question code which you used to split it.

Comment: in coordinates you have list with 3 values, not string

Answer (score 0):

In `coordinates` you have list with 3 values, not string.

You can use `apply()` with `lambda` to get one value from every list - and then you can create column with these values

```
df1['x'] = df1['coordinates'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df1['y'] = df1['coordinates'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df1['z'] = df1['coordinates'].apply(lambda x: x[2])

print(df1[['x', 'y', 'z', 'coordinates']].head())
```

You can also convert all values into 3 Series and assing to 3 new columns

```
df1[['x', 'y', 'z']] = df1['coordinates'].apply(pd.Series)

print(df1[['x', 'y', 'z', 'coordinates']].head())
```

In both resul is

```
            x          y      z                       coordinates
0 -118.895700  38.860700   5.30         [-118.8957, 38.8607, 5.3]
1 -124.254833  40.676333  27.40  [-124.2548333, 40.6763333, 27.4]
2 -116.020000  31.622500  10.19         [-116.02, 31.6225, 10.19]
3 -121.328167  36.698667   4.31  [-121.3281667, 36.6986667, 4.31]
4 -115.614500  33.140500   5.02        [-115.6145, 33.1405, 5.02]
```

Comment: Hey @furas thank you for this, I will remember from next time to put the things that I tried.

Comment: when I use the command--print(type(df1.coordinates)), I get the output as **class 'pandas.core.series.Series'** then how am I supposed to know that its a list???

Comment: `Series` is not type of data in cell but structure used by pandas to keep all data in single row or single column. It is like vector or 1D array. To check type of data in column you have to check `.dtype` - `print( df1.coordinates.dtype )` or `.dtypes` for all columns - `print( df1.dtypes )`.  But `Series` has special types only for few types like `int`, `float`, `string`, `datatime`. For other types it use `object`. So better is to ge value from cell  - ie. `[0]` - and use it with `type()`- `print( type(df1.coordinates[0]) )`.

Comment: but first I display `df1.head()` and if I see that something looks like `list` then I expect that column may have `list` in all cells.